# replacing characters of a string

Tags: java, string, substring, iteration

So I'm trying to iterate over a string and replace ever occurrence of a given substring with a new value. I can't seem to figure out what the problem with my code is because it doesn't seem to make any changes to the strings i run through it.

i create a new string nS that starts out as just “”, and am iterating through the template viewing each character as a substring s. In in every case that something needs to be replaced with a  value i append said value on to the nS, else it just appends the current substring as is.

```
@Override
public String format(String template) {
    String nS = "";
    for (int i = 0, n = template.length(); i < n; i++) {
        String s = template.substring(i, i + 1);
        switch (s) {
            case "%%":
                nS = nS.concat("%");
                break;

            case "%t":
                nS = nS.concat(String.valueOf(inSeconds()));
                break;
       }
    }
    return nS;
}
```

the actual code has many more cases but i left them out so that its not as overwhelming.

Comment: For starters, use a `StringBuilder` instead; it's much more efficient. Next, I don't think this code will compile, as you have a `case` statement outside the `switch`.

Comment: endIndex in String.substring is exclusive. you need i+2 (with a check to make sure you don't go off the end of the string)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using String replace methods?

Comment: @BenPotter presumably because the replacement is being determined programmatically.

Comment: Does this code even compile?  Also, it doesn't do what the description says: I see no replacing, just populating `nS` if `s` matches a part of `template`.

Comment: yea that extra bracket was a mistake when i posted the code, but yea i can't use string replace due to issues that would arise with other aspects of the code. My professor explained it to me earlier but i can't remember now...

Comment: i remember, its because %% is meant to escape a literal % in the output which would fail on "%%t"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ending index in the [2-arg `substring` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) is *exclusive*.

> The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.
>
> beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
>
> endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.

You are getting a substring of exactly one character, not 2.  Try `i + 2`, after the appropriate bounds-checking:

```
String s = template.substring(i, i + 2);
```

Comment: Also need to increment the index an extra position on a match, or "%%t" will be misinterpreted.

Comment: yea i know that will cause an issue i just haven't gotten to that yet since i haven't been able to replace anything at all, thanks though!

Comment: But ok that makes sense (i + 2), i feel really stupid for asking this but how do i check to see if I'm at the end of a string in java?

Comment: To stay in the string, `i` must be less than `n - 2`, so that `i + 2` isn't out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming performance is not a big issue I would do

```
public String format(String template) {
    return template.replaceAll ("%%", "\uffff")
                .replaceAll("%t", ""+inSeconds())
                .replaceAll("\uffff", "%");
}
```

Comment: Depends on the requirements. If `%%` is meant to escape a literal `%` in the output then this fails on `"%%t"`.

Comment: The \uffff character is invalid by definition.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing attempting to do sounds like you're trying to rewrite String.replace()

Given String s = "My Name Is Bob"

and you would like to replace "Bob" with "Susan" all you need to do is:

```
String s = "My Name is Bob";
String n = s.replace("Bob", "Susan");
System.out.println(n); //My Name is Susan
System.out.println(s); //My Name is Bob
```

Another option, is to break the string into a character array and iterate over it.

```
String s = "My Name is Bob";
char[] bits = s.toCharArray();
for(char c : bits) {
   // logic
}
```

Compare two characters at once:

```
String s = "My Name is Bob";
char[] bits = s.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
    if(i + 1 <= bits.length) {
       String searchFor = "" + bits[i] + bits[i + 1];
       // logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but it's difficult to see if this is what he wants from the *code* (the description certainly implies it).

Comment: The second option is tricky as it needs to compare two characters at once.

Comment: I think you mean `i < bits.length-1` so that `bits [i + 1]` doesn't blow up.